# Superclass of cpp object included in .cc file not header file

Tags: header, include, cmake, superclass

I've downloaded a toolkit (namely IRTK from Imperial college) and I have compiled and installed it using CMake.

As part of the installation it has copied all of the relevant header files into /usr/local/include

I want to use classes from this toolkit so I include a relevant header file from /usr/local/include, for example irtkFileVTKToImage.h, however this class inherits from a superclass, irtkFileToImage and the include of the superclass occurs in irtkFileVTKToImage.cc not in irtkFileVTKToImage.h.

This means when I try to include the class I get a compilation error

> error: unknown class name 'irtkFileToImage'

What should I do to be able to use these header files. I didn't write the tool kit so going through and adding all of the includes to the header files could take me a long time, is there some easier way to do this?

------ UPDATE ------

As a work around I've included the entirety of the toolkits source in my project and now my code compiles fine. Not ideal but at least it works

Comment: Could you paste the section of code? Are you compliing with the .cc?

Comment: Yeah I could, but it is a very large toolkit and it would take me a long time to go through and paste the includes for every class. Also I'd have to read the classes to try to work out which headers to include in each. I was wondering if there is some automated way of doing it, or something you can do in a makefile or with cmake to do this for me?

Comment: Where does the compilation error occurs? During the linking or before? Could you paste the whole compiler output, on pastebin or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you should compile and use the toolkit as a library, this way you will only have to include the headers of the final classes you want to use in your own code. It would be easier than trying to just use bits of it, knowing that there's a lot of dependancies.

Comment: This is what I have been trying to do. The problem is, once its installed the headers (which were placed in a global include dir) are all missing their dependancies, for some reason there dependancies were included in the .cc files.

Instead I've included the entirety of the toolkits source in my project and now I'm able to run my code, not exactly ideal but at least it works for now